# is it possible to get the value of input inside the onChange event

Tags: reactjs, onchange

consider the following;

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.props.action(this.props.id, e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <input onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
    );
  }
```

is it possible to get the value of the input field inside the onChange event.  Something like:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.props.action(this.props.id, e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <input onChange={console.log(this.value),this.handleChange}></input>
    );
  }
```

which doesn't work

Comment: `onChange={(e) => { console.log(e.target.value); this.handleChange(e) }}` but why would you?

Comment: I'm just learning react but it seems I can then use the callback directly in the onchange event in some use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` receive event object which contains the target element, you can access the target element to get the value

```
<input onChange={e => {console.log(e.target.value);this.handleChange(e) }} />
```